# DescribeStream UnknownOperationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Could you please help why do I get an UnknownOperationException for the following DynamoDBStreams request:

```
POST https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=...,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target,Signature=...
Content-Length: 100
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0
X-Amz-Date: 20151105T093459Z
X-Amz-Target: DynamoDBStreams_20120810.DescribeStream
x-amz-content-sha256: ...
{"StreamArn":"arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:147720290114:table/TestSav/stream/2015-11-04T09:47:27.834"}
```

However, the awscli command for the same stream ARN succeeds:

```
aws --debug dynamodbstreams describe-stream --stream-arn "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:147720290114:table/TestSav/stream/2015-11-04T09:47:27.834"
```

Answer (score 2):

Request should have been sent to `streams.dynamodb...com` instead of `dynamodb...com`.